# Get Array data outside while loop - php

Tags: php, arrays, function

I want to create a function to pass the values of the weeks of the year and starting date of that week. I only get output while I put the print_r($week_array) inside the while loop (which is not useful) I need to be able to get the array outside the loop. I can't see here what is happening.... Thanks.

```
function GetWeeks(){
    $year = date('Y');
    $firstDayOfYear = mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, $year);
    $firstthursday = strtotime('thursday', $firstDayOfYear);
    $firstMonday = strtotime('-3 days', $firstthursday);
    $nextMonday = strtotime('monday', $firstDayOfYear);
    $nextSunday = strtotime('sunday', $firstMonday);
    $weeknumber = "1";
    $week_array = '';

    while (date('Y', $nextMonday) == $year) {
        if ($weeknumber == 53) { 
            exit; 
        }

        if ($weeknumber == 1) {
            $fromdate = date('Y-m-d', $firstMonday);
            $todate   = date('Y-m-d', $nextSunday);
            $week_array[] = array($weeknumber => $fromdate);
            date('Y-m-d', $firstMonday);
            date('Y-m-d', $nextSunday);
            $weeknumber = $weeknumber + 1;
        }

        $nextSunday = strtotime('sunday', $nextMonday);
        $fromdate = date('Y-m-d', $nextMonday);
        $todate = date('Y-m-d', $nextSunday);
        $nextMonday = strtotime('+1 week', $nextMonday);
        $nextSunday = strtotime('+1 week', $nextSunday);
        #array_push($array, $fromdate);
        $week_array[] = array($weeknumber => $fromdate);
        $weeknumber = $weeknumber + 1;
        print_r($week_array); // Print the array values for each loop.
    }

    print_r($week_array); -> Does not work at all (dont print anything)

    return array($week_array);

}
```

Comment: `$week_array = '';` `$week_array[] =` ??? Nonsense...

Comment: @user2018824 check my answer. you are wrongly use print_r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are exit the While loop.  check this

See this `if ($weeknumber == 53) { exit}`

```
<?php
function GetWeeks(){
    $year           = date('Y');
$firstDayOfYear = mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, $year);
$firstthursday  = strtotime('thursday', $firstDayOfYear);
$firstMonday    = strtotime('-3 days', $firstthursday);
$nextMonday     = strtotime('monday', $firstDayOfYear);
$nextSunday     = strtotime('sunday', $firstMonday);

$weeknumber = "1";
//$week_array = '';
$week_array = array();
while (date('Y', $nextMonday) == $year) 
{

    if ($weeknumber == 1){
        $fromdate = date('Y-m-d', $firstMonday);
        $todate   = date('Y-m-d', $nextSunday);
        $week_array[] = array($weeknumber => $fromdate);
        date('Y-m-d', $firstMonday);
        date('Y-m-d', $nextSunday);
        $weeknumber = $weeknumber + 1;
    }
    $nextSunday     = strtotime('sunday', $nextMonday);
    $fromdate = date('Y-m-d', $nextMonday);
    $todate   = date('Y-m-d', $nextSunday);
    $nextMonday = strtotime('+1 week', $nextMonday);
    $nextSunday = strtotime('+1 week', $nextSunday);
    #array_push($array, $fromdate);

    $week_array[] = array($weeknumber => $fromdate);
    $weeknumber = $weeknumber + 1;

    if ($weeknumber == 53) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($week_array);
    exit; 
    }
            //print_r($week_array);
             //-> Print the array values for each loop.
}
 //-> Does not work at all (dont print anything)
exit;
return array($week_array);

}
GetWeeks();
?>
```

Comment: You got it right! There was an exit inside the while loop if goes to week 53, fixed it and now its returning value! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First declare right the array:

```
$week_array = array();
```

after try this:

```
$arr =  array($weeknumber => $fromdate);
array_push($week_array, $arr);
```

instead of this:

```
$week_array[] = array($weeknumber => $fromdate);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line `if ($weeknumber == 53) { exit; }` to `if ($weeknumber == 53) { break; }`